# Drupal toolbar is not showing after installing Views module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-theming

At first I installed drupal-7. I was doing some work on theme. And then I installed Views module. That was modified theme of Drupal-7. And after that my toolbar was hidden. So what can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Vist "yoursite.com"/admin/modules and check that the toolbar module is not un selected.

If its still selected, try installing the admin_menu toolbar, it looks a lot nice, and comes with a smooth dropdown menu.

https://drupal.org/project/admin_menu

Or, you say you were doing work on your theme, check that you didnt set anything with a very high z-index that would cover the toolbar